# Install without boot disc

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu (or Lubuntu, more precisely) on a machine where BIOS does not allow be to boot from an USB (and there is no CD/DVD). I have browsed the alternatives in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation), but they are all quite advanced, or at least far beyond my understanding of Ubuntu. Is there any relatively simple way to make run an .iso off a small partition of the harddrive, or loading in into the RAM somehow, to make it work as like if I had run it from a USB startup disk? The computer currently has Ubuntu 14.10 installed, but I'd like to all completely fresh install, wiping everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can run from a hard drive!  A hard drive is just an internal version of a USB drive (for your purposes) so you can do this no problem.  Just throw the iso onto a partition and you should be good to go.

NOTE:  I haven't tried this myself but I know of people who have.